# Big Query Compute Average time between two Custom Events

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm attempting to determine the average time between two events in my Firebase analytics using BigQuery.  The table looks something like this:

[image]

I'd like to collect the timstamp_micros for the LOGIN_CALL and LOGIN_CALL_OK events, subtract LOGIN_CALL from LOGIN_CALL_OK and compute the average for this across all rows.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AVG(
(SELECT
  event.timestamp_micros
FROM
  `table`,
  UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
where event.name = "LOGIN_CALL_OK") - 
(SELECT
  event.timestamp_micros
FROM
  `table`,
  UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
where event.name = "LOGIN_CALL"))
from `table`
```

I've managed to list either the low or the hi numbers, but any time I try to do any math on them I run into errors I'm struggling to pull apart.  This approach above seems like it should work but i get the following error:

> Error: Scalar subquery produced more than one element

I read this error to mean that each of the UNNEST() functions is returning an array, and not single value which is causing AVG to barf.  I've tried to unnest once and apply a "low" and "hi" name to the values, but can't figure out how to filter using the event_dim.name correctly.

Comment: You need to have some kind of ID to connect LOGIN_CALL and LOGIN_CALL_OK to do meaningful difference between them.

Comment: Not sure I follow?  These are packed into single rows in the BigQuery DB... the names of the events would be the ID I believe?

Comment: Ah sorry I think i follow a bit further now - there is an ID in the table, i just didn't include it above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't fully test this one but maybe this might work for you:

```
WITH data AS(
  SELECT STRUCT('1' as user_id) user_dim, ARRAY< STRUCT<date string, name string, timestamp_micros INT64> >  [('20170610', 'EVENT1', 1497088800000000), ('20170610', 'LOGIN_CALL', 1498088800000000), ('20170610', 'LOGIN_CALL_OK', 1498888800000000), ('20170610', 'EVENT2', 159788800000000), ('20170610', 'LOGIN_CALL', 1599088800000000), ('20170610', 'LOGIN_CALL_OK', 1608888800000000)] event_dim union all
  SELECT STRUCT('2' as user_id) user_dim, ARRAY< STRUCT<date string, name string, timestamp_micros INT64> >  [('20170610', 'EVENT1', 1497688500400000), ('20170610', 'LOGIN_CALL', 1497788800000000)] event_dim UNION ALL
  SELECT STRUCT('3' as user_id) user_dim, ARRAY< STRUCT<date string, name string, timestamp_micros INT64> >  [('20170610', 'EVENT1', 1487688500400000), ('20170610', 'LOGIN_CALL', 1487788845000000), ('20170610', 'LOGIN_CALL_OK', 1498888807700000)] event_dim
)

SELECT
  AVG(time_diff) avg_time_diff
FROM(
SELECT
  CASE WHEN e.name = 'LOGIN_CALL' AND LEAD(NAME,1) OVER(PARTITION BY user_dim.user_id ORDER BY timestamp_micros ASC) = 'LOGIN_CALL_OK' THEN TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(LEAD(TIMESTAMP_MICROS, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY user_dim.user_id ORDER BY timestamp_micros ASC)), TIMESTAMP_MICROS(TIMESTAMP_MICROS), day) END time_diff
FROM data,
UNNEST(event_dim) e
WHERE e.name in ('LOGIN_CALL', 'LOGIN_CALL_OK')
)
```

I've simulated 3 users with the same schema that you have in [Firebase Schema](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en).

Basically, I first applied the `UNNEST` operation so to have each value of `event_dim.name`. Then applied filter to get only the events that you are interested in, that is, "LOGIN_CALL" and "LOGIN_CALL_OK".

As Mosha commented above, you do need to have some identification for these rows as otherwise you won't know which event succeeded which so that's why the partitioning of the analytical functions takes the `user_dim.user_id` as input as well.

After that, it's just [TIMESTAMP](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp-functions) operations to get the differences when appropriate (when the leading event is "LOGIN_CALL_OK" and the current one being "LOGIN_CALL" then take the difference. This is expressed in the CASE expression).

You can choose in the [TIMESTAMP_DIFF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp_diff) function which part of the date you want to analyze, such as seconds, minutes, days and so on.

Comment: Thanks, trying it out now.

Comment: Query runs, but i just get "avg dif 0.0"

Comment: Yea if i remove the AVG it looks like it's getting either 0's or nulls for all time_diffs. There's no guarantee the events are right next to each other, they could be separated by other events (session start being the most common).   This does look like a step in the right direction though, much thanks.

Comment: Also it probably wasn't clear from the original photo, but these events are all in one row, one row for each user session.  That may not be ideal - these analytics are kind of a mess and may need some rewrites.

Comment: @NathanielD.Waggoner hmm this is weird. Could you please confirm if these events are being saved in the same `timestamp_micros`? Also, what happens if you change the date precision to 'second' or 'minute' in the `timestamp_diff` function?

Comment: Thanks - so the timestamps are definitely in the same column.  Changing the precision got me some values that seem to make some decent sense!

Comment: Looks like messing with the precision was the fix here.  Thanks a lot.  Still getting a lot of nulls, but I think that's because some rows don't have any Login events, and in some rows they're farther apart than 1 in the LEAD call.  Is there a way to search more arbitrarily than LEAD?  Marking as accepted regardless.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to know it worked :)! The `NULL` fields are expected indeed. What do you mean by searching more arbitrarily? Do you have an example?

Comment: So If i understand this correctly - the LEAD(NAME, 1) searches for the very next "row" of data to have the name NAME - where "row" is the UNNEST(event_dim) data.  Let's assume I didn't know where the two events I wanted were located in relation to one another within that event_dim - say there were some events:

E1
E2
E3
E5
E4 (maybe a network call completed here).  Is there a way to do that LEAD search that is less specific to locational relationship?  Does that make sense?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference, notice that I added to the `WHERE` clause the filter: `e.name in ('LOGIN_CALL', 'LOGIN_CALL_OK')` so regardless of how many events are there between the two, it all gets removed and only the desired events remain. This being the case, the lead(name,1) is just the operation to verify if one event succeeded the other. You can play around with the users I simulated as well to verify this one.

Comment: Ah ok yea, so I was re-reading the docs just now and thought that might be the case.  Thank you for clarifying, very helpful.